# Bacon.js accumulator

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

my_Stream is data I want to accumulate and assign to variable for further processing. My question: How do I get the contents of the variable the_string to console.log ONCE THE STREAM IS FINISHED?

```
my_Stream.onValue(function(value) {
 the_string = the_string.concat(value);
});
```

My full code can be found in github issue page: [github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/1778](http://here%20is%20the%20github%20issue%20page%20with%20my%20code:%20github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/1778)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is [`fold`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#observable-fold), which scans the stream and outputs a value only when the stream ends.

```
const stream = Bacon.sequentially(100, ["Hello", "world"])    
stream.log("stream")
const concatenated = stream.fold("", (a,b) => a + b)
concatenated.log("concatenated")
```

http://jsbin.com/yodudiqovi/edit?html,js,console

Comment: In jsbin it works but doesn't pass the unit test . To give a bit of context, I created the stream using Bacon.fromBinder as a buffer for a http request, response. Yes I might have used a simpler buffer lib (eg. bl.js). Using Bacon.js as a buffer seems like overkill.

What's frustrating is that onValue() works to log() the contents of the stream but doesn't allow chaining to fold().

Comment: Do you have a working example of your code that you could share? Without seeing the code it's very hard to help you.

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow, can't get code  formatting right.. so here is the github issue page with my code:
https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/1778

Comment: I added a comment in the gist, but the problem was that your stream never ends, so the fold never outputs a value.

Comment: Yes agreed fold method is the right choice. I was running into errors from your example because I was using Javascript in ES5 syntax which results in an error. 

`const concatenated = stream.fold("", (a,b) => a + b)`  <---works
'var concatenated =  stream.fold("", function (a,b){ a + b})` <----does not work

I have to assume Bacon.js works more reliably in ES6 syntax

Comment: You're missing the "return" keyword in your ES5 example. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm so used to writing ES6 that I didn't even think about using ES5. Actually "Bacon.js works more reliably in ES6 syntax" is not true, but I do recommend using ES6 in Bacon.js, as the shorter function syntax really makes the FRP style code easier to write and read. That's the same reason that @raimohanska wrote Bacon.js in CoffeeScript.